# Parse text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of text: 
`javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$Body$test", "", true, "doc", "", false, true))`

I want to get `doc` which is 4th element in `(`

How can I get this using javascript? Should I use Regex for this?

Comment: What do you mean? From within the function?

Comment: No, consider this as a simple text - not a function.

Comment: you COULD use regex for this, but my question is - why? What is the problem you are trying to solve that's lead you to want this?

Comment: I need the "doc" which is 4th element in WebForm_PostBackOptions. Hope I am clear.

Comment: that makes lots of sense, my question is, why do you want to be extracting a random variable from a string of javascript?

Comment: Because that is what I *NEED* in my program. Do not bother. Niddro already posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Splitting the text string up in segments and isolating the 4th one:

```
var txt = 'javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$Body$test", "", true, "doc", "", false, true))';

var myArray = txt.split(",");

var myVariable = myArray[3].trim();

alert(myVariable);
```